# localtunnel not generating url string on Windows 10

Tags: facebook-graph-api, wamp, localtunnel

I have followed this guide in setting up my localtunnel:
https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/accessible-local-web-server/

however, when I run the following command `lt –port 80` nothing is showing. I started looking for this solution since Facebook seems to have stopped localhost access to FB.iu() method for sharing content on their site.

I have tried running as admin while disabling firewall and McAfees Antivirus Scan. I have used ngrok before now too but Facebook rejects it for no clear reason.

Below is an image of the steps taken:
[image: lt setup information]

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get my way around this localhost tunneling issue using ngrok.

I noticed I'm expected to add additional domain names under `App Domains` in Facebook APP settings. So I added `ngrok.io` as an additional APP Domain and WHALAH! everything started working for the FB.ui() method.